# need help automatically creating multiple paragraphs in a google doc from a google script

Tags: google-apps-script

i am trying to create a google document that has a paragraph automatically generated from data on a google spreadsheet. most of the information i have found shows how to create one document or one page for each set of data but i need to generate one paragraph and have the script create as many pages as is necessary. this is my first google script (and i'm new to scripting in general) so there may be some obvious errors.

here is what i have for the script so far:

```
function scriptListGen() {  

  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  var firstName = mySheet.getRange("B3").getValue();  
  var lastName = mySheet.getRange("C3").getValue();  
  var dispo1 = "Prescription Left With Dr.";  
  var dispo2 = "Prescription Recieved";  
  var dispo3 = "Prescription Denied";  
  var notes = "Notes:"; 
  var date = "Date:";  
  var content = firstName + " " + lastName + "  " + dispo1 + dispo2 + dispo3 + notes;  

  var templateDocID = ScriptProperties.getProperty("listTemplateDocID");  
  var docID = DocsList.getFileById(templateDocID).makeCopy().getId();  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);  
  var body = doc.getActiveSection();  
  body.insertParagraph(1, content);  
  body.insertHorizontalRule(2);  
}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evan,
  I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'add as many pages as possible'.  But assuming you mean that you want to have the information from your spreadsheet flow from one page to the next as needed, I think you'll want to use

```
body.appendParagraph  rather than insertParagraph.
```

Here's some code I'm using that does a similar process.

```
function ReadFromSelectedTab(doc,SelectedTab,lHeading2style,lHeading3style,CatCount)
{
var doctoprocess = UserProperties.getProperty('doctoprocess');
var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(doctoprocess);
var sheets =  workbook.getSheets();
var sheet =  workbook.getSheetByName(SelectedTab);


if (sheet != null) {
// The code below will make the sheet active in the active workbook
workbook.setActiveSheet(workbook.getSheets()[sheet.getIndex()-1]);
var lastRow = workbook.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = workbook.getLastColumn();
var lastACell = workbook.getRange("A"+lastRow);
Logger.log("Last Column: " + lastColumn)
for (var q = 0; q < lastRow; ++q)
     {
var Category = sheet.getRange(q+1,1).getValue();
var Question1 = sheet.getRange(q+1,2).getValue();
var Question2 = sheet.getRange(q+1,3).getValue();

var Column3Heading = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue()
if (Column3Heading = 'ANSWERS')
{
var answers = true;
}
if (Category.length > 0) {
**var head2 = doc.appendParagraph(CatCount +".  " + Category);**

head2.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3); 
          doc.appendParagraph(" ");
       CatCount++;
     }
     if (Question1.length > 0) {
       var quest1 = doc.**appendParagraph**(Question1);
       quest1.setAttributes(lHeading2style);
     }
     if (Question2.length > 0 && q>0) {

       var quest2 = doc.appendParagraph("     " + Question2);
       if ( answers != true)
       {
       quest2.setAttributes(lHeading3style);
       }
       else
       { quest2.setItalic(true).setFontSize(8).setBold(true); }
     }

   }    //  for (var q = 0; q < lastRow; ++q)
}          //  if (sheet != null) 
}
```

So the code will iterate through tabs I selected, and then go through the various rows to pull out information.  The information is formatted using some pre-defined headingstyles into a Document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Joe, your assumption was correct, i meant to say "as many pages as necessary". this will help tremendously but i have a few questions:  

1) what is in the "doc" and "SelectedTab" variables?  
2) are you creating a new document before you call this function?  
3) i'm not clear on what is happening in this block:  
    'var Category = sheet.getRange(q+1,1).getValue();  
    var Question1 = sheet.getRange(q+1,2).getValue();  
    var Question2 = sheet.getRange(q+1,3).getValue();  '
particularly the .getRange(q+1,1) piece.  

again your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: also does "doctoprocess" contain the doc ID?

Comment: sorry, one more question, i want to set a smaller font for 3 of my variables but i get the message: "TypeError: Cannot find function setFontSize in object Request Left With Dr.. (line 48)".    

i'm attempting to use "dispo1.setFontSize(8):

Comment: Hello Evan.. that's the problem with code.. snippets, there's so much more that's outside of what I posted :)
doc is a new Google Doc that I previously created.  
SelectedTab is a text value of various tabs in the spreadsheet (ss) I'm reading from.  I allow the user to select particular ones to move to the Doc. the `var Category..` you mention is going thru the ss getting contents and placing them into variables we write to later.
doctoprocess is the ID of the ss I'm reading from.

Comment: Here's where I set some styles to use in the original code. It's created outside of the function in original code and passed as a parameter.

`// Formatting styles
var 2Heading1style = {};
   lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL;
   lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
   lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
`

Comment: Joe, i've got everything working as i wanted (thanks again for your help) except the formatting. i have:  
    var dispostyle = {}; 
      dispostyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL; 
      dispostyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 8; 
      dispostyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

then later:    dispo1.setAttributes(dispostyle);

but i get an error "can't find function setAttributes".  i also don't know why my formatting isn't working in the comments like it was for the original question.

Comment: Evan, it looks like you may have a problem with how 'dispo1' is defined.  in my code it is the same as quest2 here:
`var quest2 = doc.appendParagraph("     " + Question2);
       quest2.setAttributes(2Heading1style);`
so you should make sure `dispo1 = doc.appendParagraph`

Comment: ahh, yes that would be my problem dispo1 simply contains a string of text. i read the documentation but can't seem to find a way to set the style for that variable.